# What would I synchronize on here?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

#### The code fragments first...

```
final public class ExampleClass {

final public class OperationQueue {

    final private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Operation> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public Operation newOp(Command command) {
        Operation op = new Operation(command);
        queue.add(op);
        return op;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }

    private Operation remove() {
        return queue.remove();
    }

}
final public OperationQueue opQueue = new OperationQueue();

public void doSomething() {

     synchronized (opQueue.queue) { // or synchronized(opQueue) ?
        while (!opQueue.isEmpty()) {
            process(opQueue.remove());
        }
    }
 }

}
```

#### My Question...

What would I need to synchronize on? `opQueue.queue`? or `opQueue`? or does it not matter?

Actuallly `opQueue.queue` is only even accessible through the quirk that it is in an `inner/nested class`.

Comment: How many threads are going to call `doSomething()`?  The `synchronized` block in doSomething() serves no purpose whatsoever if only one thread calls it.  Where is the synchronization at the other end of the queue?

Comment: I'm not sure, depends on the situation - threads are created dynamically but multiple, but problem was solved by the answer about `poll()`.. it "atomicizes" the code so now it should be Thread-Safe because `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is safe if only one interface method is called (those methods have `atomic` behaviour), I think - from what I was reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to do [`poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll--) in your case

```
public void doSomething() 
{
    Operation op;
    while( null != (op=queue.poll()) )
        process( op );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does not really matter much which object you take lock on, but yes it should be relevant.

The only thing you need to take care of is that for other operations on the shared resource which you are trying to protect should use the same lock.